# Share Jwt token between two asp core api

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, jwt, token

I'm having trouble here.
I'm trying to build a second asp core api that will share a jwt token created buy my main aspcore api aka : authorization server.
But i can't get it to work.

The idea is that my angular client will get a token from my main api (authorization server) and send this same token to get data from an other api which will have to check with the auth server i guess if the token is valid.

I think this is somewhere in the configure otpion :

```
            .AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    ValidateLifetime = true,
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    ValidIssuer = Configuration["Jwt:Issuer"],
                    ValidAudience = Configuration["Jwt:Audience"],
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["Jwt:Key"])),
                           // Ensure the token audience matches our audience value (default true):
                    ValidateAudience = true,

                };
```

And i have in my config file :

```
  "Jwt": {
    "Key": "METAPRODUCTIQUE2904",
    "Audience": "http://localhost:52771/",
    "Issuer": "http://localhost:52771",
  },
```

Then main app run on port 52771 for test and my current secondary app on port 52772
But i think i did something wrong but can't figure what
I'd greatly appreciate some ideas from you guys

Comment: Are you using Identity Server? Otherwise I would recommend doing that. This is a good introduction with a similar scenario as you are trying to accomplish: [https://youtu.be/KmrTO3__Huw](https://youtu.be/KmrTO3__Huw) and the docs are at [http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/)

Answer (score 4):

First, Let's find out how it's going to work.

```
1) user ---------------------(Get Token) ---------------------> AuthServer
2) AuthServer -----------------(Token)------------------------> user
3) user ----------(Request with Token as auth header)---------> OtherServers
```

In Step 2 the `AuthServer` checks the user permissions and creates a package of data that contains user info, permissions, and other stuff, then it encrypts that with the `key` you provided to a base64 string which we call it `Token`.

We have the `key` in other servers too. When a request reaches to them they first try to decrypt it with the `key`. And if everything goes right, Now the other server has the user info and permissions and other stuff.

So the `AuthServer` does not need to be connected to other servers and they can work with each other.

In the `startup` class of both Services you should have the following code :

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            ...
            // JWT
            services.AddAuthentication(x =>
            {
                x.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                x.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            }).AddJwtBearer(x =>
            {
                x.RequireHttpsMetadata = false;
                x.SaveToken = true;
                x.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII
                        .GetBytes("MySpecialKey")),
                    ValidIssuer = "MainServer",
                    ValidAudience = "Sample",
                    ValidateIssuer = false,
                    ValidateAudience = false
                };
            });
            ...
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            ...
            app.UseAuthentication();
            ...
        }
```

And in one of the services of `authorization server` you should implement a method to generate tokens for registered users :

```
public async Task<string> GenToken()
        {
            // check if the user has the required permissions
            ....

            // authentication successful so generate jwt token
            var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
            var tokenDescriptor = new SecurityTokenDescriptor
            {
                Subject = new ClaimsIdentity(new Claim[]
                {
                    new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "Username"),
                }),
                Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(1),
                SigningCredentials = new SigningCredentials(new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII
                    .GetBytes("MySpecialKey")), SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256Signature)
            };
            var token = tokenHandler.CreateToken(tokenDescriptor);
            var tokenString = tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);

            return tokenString;
        }
```

Now you can use the `[Authorize]` attribute on top of controllers or APIs.

Each request to `[Authorize]` controllers or APIs should contain a header with key `Authorization` and value of `bearer USERTOKEN`

Comment: I have done that but can't getg the second server to reach the first one .... can we exchange more about that by mail or send me a private msg on stackoverflow ? Would gladly appreciate

Comment: I have updated the answer to contains the logic. the servers do not need to be connected cause the auth is using encryption to do the job.

Comment: Thanks amin but for example what do you put as values for  ValidIssuer = "MainServer",
                    ValidAudience = "Sample", like  http://localhost:52771 and http://localhost:52772 or just simple key for each one ?

Comment: These values are optional, you can put anything, the point is that you can validate them after decrypting the token on other servers.